# I want to install Kali Linux side by side on my machine which is currently running on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: system-installation

I want to install Kali Linux side by side on my machine which is currently running on Ubuntu 12.10.Is it possble and if it is could you instruct me how?

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly possible, I had it installed in a free partition next to 12.04 without problems.

Make sure to use manual partitioning, as by default it tries to use the whole disk.

I did **not** install `Kali`'s grub in the MBR (installer asks you if you want that). Instead after installation I booted in Ubuntu and ran `update-grub`: at the next reboot there was a menu option in grub to start the Kali installation.